# 401 code when using here suggestions api with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, here-api

I'm using the here api with an autocomplete text input. For the suggestions data I'm trying to use https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest endpoint but I get this error (The API works fine on Postman)

```
Request failed with status code 401
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:53:6 in handleLoad
at node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in 
EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in 
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This is the function I used for the get request :

```
const searchSuggestion = async () => {
try {
  const response = await hereSuggestionsApi.get(
    https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest
    ?apiKey=API_KEY
    &q=${destination}
    &in=countryCode:DZA
    &at=36.7762,3.05997
    &lang=fr
    &limit=5
  );
  setSuggestions(response);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
};
```

Comment: [401](https://httpstatuses.com/401) means you're unauthorized. Either your API key is invalid or you need to add some kind of credentials to your request.

Comment: @Reyno I'm using the apiKey isn't that enough ? I tested the request on Postman and it is working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you left the brackets around the API key, unless you are specifying the key it through string interpolation (in that case the `$` sign is missing from your example). Please try:

```
const searchSuggestion = async () => {
try {
  const response = await hereSuggestionsApi.get(
    https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest
    ?apiKey=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=${destination}
    &in=countryCode:DZA
    &at=36.7762,3.05997
    &lang=fr
    &limit=5
  );
  setSuggestions(response);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
};
```

Comment: I'm using the string directely. In the question I replaced it with the `{API_KEY}` just to not use the real apiKey. Thanks, I'm gonna edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked  the logs for your app_id starting  with pRz***************** for the last 10 days. And we have found around 37 requests with the invalid query parameters in the request.

Below are the some of the sample of  request which our system have received from your app_id  with invalid query parameter.
[image]

Please refer the autosuggest section of below document on how to pass the countrycode,circle,bbox in the "IN"  query string.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html